# How to extract fields from an escaped JSON(nested) in splunk?

Tags: json, splunk, splunk-query

I'm looking for help in extracting "allowedSourceAddressPrefix" field/value from a JSON. This field is an escaped JSON string inside a nested JSON. Following is the JSON tree

```
- properties (extracted by splunk)
  - /subscription/..../.../  (dynamic field)
    - ports (escaped json)
      - allowedSourceAddressPrefix (nested json)
```

The allowedSourceAddressPrefix takes values of single ipaddress (or) multiple ip addresses (or) *.

I have tried various rex patterns but failed in extracting the required field, Any help is appreciated. Following is the JSON that has the required field

```js
properties: {
  "User": "johndoe@contoso.com",
  "/subscriptions/3483b2ca-02cf-4ff6-92af-99326c8fac7f/resourceGroups/apple-dev/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/gjappledev": "{\"id\":\"/subscriptions/3483b2ca-02cf-4ff6-92af-99326c8fac7f/resourceGroups/apple-dev/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/gjappledev\",\"ports\":[{\"number\":3389,\"allowedSourceAddressPrefix\":\"*\",\"endTimeUtc\":\"2022-03-21T1:50:39.1599446Z\"}]}",
  "Justification": null
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know some of the regular expressions you've tried so we don't repeat them.

Have you tried the `spath` command to parse the JSON?

Perhaps this `rex` command will help

```
| rex "allowedSourceAddressPrefix\\\\\":\\\\\"(?<allowedSourceAddressPrefix>[^\\\]+)"
```

Comment: Wow, great, this worked. I was trying the following command with help from splunk community. The following command worked well with a makeresults example but failed with actual data. Your's working on actual data, thanks again. And if you could let me know what's wrong on the following command?
<splunkCommand>
| rex field=properties "allowedSourceAddressPrefix\\\\\":\\\\\"(?<allowedSourceAddressPrefix>.*?)\\\\\""
<splunkCommand>

Comment: I suspect the Community suggestion failed because there is no `properties` field.  My answer uses the `_raw` field to avoid depending on any other extractions.

Comment: Yup, you got me there, well the community too suggested without properties. That's my addition and the community recommendation too is working. But why not mention field, I mean why it works only for _raw?

Comment: If `rex` only works with the _raw field then it must be because the specific field doesn't exist or has different content than expected.